# Laravel 5.8 Eloquent whereBetween fails

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am stuck with an error on an `Eloquent` query.

My query:

```
$mtd_hits = Usage::selectRaw("
        SUM(table_hits) AS hits,
    ")
    ->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [$from_date, $to_date])
    ->first();
```

In my `Usage` class:

```
public $timestamps = true;

protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

My `$from_date`and `$to_date` are `Carbon` instances:

`$from_date`:

```
Carbon @1556323200 {#1416 ▼
  date: 2019-04-27 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)
}
```

`$to_date`:

```
Carbon @1558915200 {#1622 ▼
  date: 2019-05-27 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)
}
```

By my query fails with:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from `usage` where `user_id` = ? and `created_at` between ? and ? limit 1' at line 3 
(SQL: select SUM(table_hits) AS hits, from `usage` where `user_id` = 2 and `created_at` between 2019-04-27 00:00:00 and 2019-05-27 00:00:00 limit 1)
```

Apologies in advance if this is a silly question.

Comment: Remove the comma from your raw query.

Comment: #FMD! Been a long year already! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its all about your raw query !
try removing `,` from your code
also you can see your query by using `->toSql()` method